# How To Get Currently Active Tool in Bokeh Figure

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm interested in finding the currently selected tool out of the toolbar on a figure. Right now I have a customized toolbar, and I want to be able to get the active tool in a Python callback for a bokeh app.

```
def scrollCallback():
    # check if PanTool() is currently selected/active

fig = figure(...)
fig.toolbar.active_drag = None
fig.toolbar.active_scroll = None
fig.tools = [PanTool(), BoxZoomTool(), ResetTool()]
fig.on_event(events.Pan, scrollCallback)
```

Comment: In a `CustomJS` clallback in standalone HTML output? In a real Python callback in a Bokeh server application? You need to describe your situation in more detail, and also describe (with code snippets) what you have tried already or think you might try,

Comment: @bigreddot Sorry, updated with more description. Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.3.4 this information is not exposed to the Python public API. You can inspect an internal property `.active` on the JavaScript side (e.g. from a `CustomJS` callback). a kludgy workaround to get the information to a Python callback might be to have a `CustomJS` look at all the tools to see which are active, and set some value on, say, an invisible glyph, that the Python side can monitor for changes. I don't think that's a good solution, but probably the best one available. You could propose making the active state available publicly as a new feature request by [making an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues). Now that *read-only* properties exist, it might be simple and safe to allow this internal property to join the public API.